# How can i extract pdf tables other than tabula

Tags: python, tabula

I have an working script in which we have to read the pdf tables using tabula package , but as tabula is dependent on Java 8 and we have to use java 6 and below due to some internal tools , how can we read  the pdf tables of the tables.

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df_list = tabula.read_pdf(current_file, pages="all", lattice = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to convert a pdf document to an excel spreadsheet:**

*Option 1, using the pdf_tables API:*

1. Install pdf_tables with
   `pip install git+https://github.com/pdftables/python-pdftables-api.git`
2. Get an account [here](https://pdftables.com/pdf-to-excel-api)

Once you have everything installed you can run this code:

```
import pdftables_api

c = pdftables_api.Client('my-api-key')
c.xlsx('input.pdf', 'output') 
#replace c.xlsx with c.csv to convert to CSV 
#replace c.xlsx with c.xml to convert to XML
#replace c.xlsx with c.html to convert to HTML
#This is documentation code for your information
```

Don't forget to replace  my-api-key with your api key, input.pdf with the path of your pdf, and ouput to the path of the directory you would like to save the output excel document to.

*Option 2, using textract to read the pdf and then writing to the spreadsheet using xlwt:*

1. Install textract with `pip install textract`
2. Install xlwt with `pip install xlwt`

Once you have installed the dependencies, you can run the following code:

```
import textract
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension") #You'll have to change this to your path to the file
```

I do not know about how your pdf is organized but you'll have to figure out how to write to the excel document from there. (you can use `sheet1.write(1, 0, 'Data')` where 1 and 0 are your coordinates on your spreadsheet.

I personally think you should use the pdf_tables API instead of manually doing the conversion.